# Moving the media/downloadable directory to external server

Tags: database, media, magento-1.9

I need to set a seperate location for the directory "media/downloadable/" to an external server address. The predicted filesize (TIFF data) exceeds 290 Gb!. The media folder will contain aprox. 90Gb of jpeg media data. This will be "fast" storage and is easily acomplische in web/secure and web/insecure setting in the admin. 
There is no seperate setting for media/downloadable. Any idea how to do this?